# How should I use function setInterval() in recursive function,like mergeSort?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

MergerSort function as a recursive,I want to show each step when calling merge_sort_auto but it didn't work as expected!

```
function merge_sort_auto(arr,start,end){
        showArray(arr);//I want to show my array here!
        if (start < end) {
            setTimeout(function() {     //can setInterval work here? 
            var mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
            merge_sort_auto(arr, start, mid);//first part
            merge_sort_auto(arr, mid + 1, end);//second part
            //merge here
            var ARR = new Array(end - start + 1);
            var k = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 0;
            while (k1 != mid - start + 1 && k2 != end - mid) {
                if (arr[start + k1] < arr[mid + 1 + k2]) {
                    ARR[k++] = arr[start + k1++];
                } else {
                    ARR[k++] = arr[mid + 1 + k2++];
                }
            }
            if (k1 == mid - start + 1) {
                while (k2 < end - mid) {
                    ARR[k++] = arr[mid + 1 + k2++];
                }
            }
            if (k2 == end - mid) {
                while (k1 < mid - start + 1) {
                    ARR[k++] = arr[start + k1++];
                }
            }
            k = 0;
            for (var x = start; x <= end; x++) {
                arr[x] = ARR[k++];
            }
            },100);
        }
}
```

It didn't work as expected ,why is that?Thank you!

Comment: So you want to log/show the individual steps somewhere, for educational/teaching purposes? Trying to ”squeeze” setTimeout into that algorithm is likely to get rather messy – I’d rather recommend that you “record” all steps first, by putting the output you want to show for each step into an array, and then output the content of that array afterwards – doing that step-by-step with a timeout would be much easier to implement.

Comment: Why would you want to use setTimeout for a sort algorithm? This algorithm should be synchronous, and setTimeout (or setInterval) will make is asynchronous. Why not simply a recursive algorithm?

Comment: @jlowcs I want to draw the elements in the array like a in a debug view in the showArrary(arr) function,maybe it's not a good way.

Comment: @CBroe I do this just for fun,the setTimeout function make the stack don't work correctly when I finally debuged it.

Comment: You don't need setTimeout to do that. Also, there's no guarantee that the setTimeout callbacks will be called in the order you've defined them. So, definitely not a good idea.